# Как сделать фоновый цикл в bat файле

Tags: node.js, bat

Мне не получается сделать так, чтобы на фоне был поставлен какой то цикл, например node script.js в цикле, а в командной строке можно было писать команды или отвечать на choice и тд во время работы цикла. Важно - Чтобы работало console.log во время цикла, choice и тд.

Вот код:

```
:loop

node script.js
choice /n /c q /m ""
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto exit

goto loop

:exit
exit
```

Comment: Мне кажется, вы что то не то делаете... Добавьте в ворпос информацию,  какой результат вы хотите получить. Скорее всего вы пошли не тем путем и задачу можно решить иначе

Comment: Нет, иначе никак. Если вызывать посредством call новый bat файл, то да, цикл начинается, но цикл загораживает например choice, и тот перестает работать. А цикл дальше циклит

Comment: Так а что вы делаете, что вам надо в цикле запускать ноду(причем похоже вы туда параметры не передаете)? Может проще поднять мини приклад в самом nodejs?

Comment: Нет, вы наверно не поняли, нужно чтобы создался постоянный цикл, и чтобы этот цикл не перекрывал просьбы choice и другие. А также во время просьбы choice и тд выводились надписи при помощи цикла. В цикле стоит штука которая получает данные из файла и отправляет в консоль.

Comment: В любом случае, так сделать нельзя. В цикле либо все крутится, либо все ждут чего то. В целом, выглядит, как идевательство, в цикле запускать процесс ноды. Вам надо пересмотреть аритектуру вашего решения. Поднимите процесс на ноде, пусть слушает какой нибудь порт, и туда данные передавайте при необходимости.

Comment: Я за 2 дня выучил основы bat файла, теперь не допераю как сделать так. Но вашего ответа не понял про порт тд. Это не связано с сетью это оффлайн